# console.time vs window.performance.measure

Tags: javascript, time, performance-testing

Disclaimer: The following snippet can run slowly and/or lock up in most browsers due to a performance issue in the running library. However this illustrates an oddity that I can't seem to resolve.

Question: Why in the below snippet is there such a significant difference in timing between console.time and window.performance.measure?

Clarification: console.time is reporting millisecond level timing, where window.performance.measure is providing accurate timings of approx 40s.

[image]

```js
    import { unified } from "unified";
    import remarkParse from "remark-parse";
    import remarkRehype from "remark-rehype";
    import rehypeStringify from "rehype-stringify";

    const sourceMarkdown = `
    1${" ".repeat(75000)}2
    `;

    document.getElementById("source").innerHTML = sourceMarkdown;

    try {
      console.time("unified-pipeline");
      window.performance.mark("unified-pipeline");
      unified()
        .use(remarkParse)
        .use(remarkRehype)
        .use(rehypeStringify)
        .process(sourceMarkdown)
        .then((file) => {
          document.getElementById(
            "result"
          ).contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = String(file);
          console.timeEnd("unified-pipeline");
          console.log(window.performance.measure("unified-pipeline"));
        });
    } catch (err) {
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = err;
    }
```

Comment: so what is the difference??

Comment: Sorry that was a big oversight, there was approximately a 40second discrepancy between timings I have edit the OP to clarify.

Comment: This question is still outstanding, while there was a minor issue in usage there is still a significant discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are misusing `performance.measure` and therefore measuring different things.

You are only providing [`measureName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure#syntax):

> If only measureName is specified, the start timestamp is set to zero, and the end timestamp (which is used to calculate the duration) is the value that would be returned by Performance.now().

...thereby measuring the time since the [time origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp#the_time_origin) rather than the time since the start mark.

The first parameter should be `measureName` (a *new* unrelated string), and the **second** parameter should be the name of the `startMark`.

```
window.performance.measure("anything here", "unified-pipeline")
```

Comment: Good call, I did miss the measureName causing the performance to be measured from the start of the page load until now. After correcting the issue. There is still roughly a 38s discrepancy.

Comment: any idea why there is still a significant difference after updating to use the appropriate measure parameters?